# Различие release\debug MSVS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

При сборке проекта в режиме Release - все ок, ошибок нет.
При попытке собрать этот же проект получая подобные ошибки:

```
Error   1   The type 'InScripting.IInPictureFigures' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'InScripting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   D:\Job\proj\IntelligenceSoftware CacheGenerator\Data\Ingeo\IngeoDestinationLayer.cs 56  25  IntelligenceSoftware CacheGenerator
```

Данная (и еще парочка) библиотек являются com библиотеками, на которые добавлены ссылки (reference).
Сосбтвенно вопрос - почему так?

Comment: Может быть, у вас различные настройки для debug- и release-конфигураций? Кстати, почему бы вам и правда не добавить ссылку, раз компилятор её требует?

Попробуйте ещё Rebuild, возможно, ошибка появится и в Debug-конфигурации.

Comment: ссылку на либу? она только в com, туда регистрировал exe